# Проблема с примением стилей CSS

Tags: css

При примении стиля CSS, то применяется бутстрап, как мне изменить это?Через !important?
Хочу другой, но приоритет отдаёт не тому, что мне нужно. Смотрю в браузере и это действительно так. Написал в свой стиль !important и всё заработало. Есть ли другие методы или что можете посоветовать.

Comment: Приоритет можно обойти несколькими способами. Зависимо какой какой класс используете в бутстрапе. Покажите код

Answer (score 0):

Конечно, просто свои стили переместить под bootstrap, и они их переопределят, если же в bootstrap нет свойства  !important